# How to specify an end-line character in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

This code below works:

```
IO.foreach("C:\\Users\\zeus\\Desktop\\db.txt") do |line|
  puts line
end
```

But **I want to print each character one by one**.
The problem is that I cannot specify the end of line. I have an input file as follows:

> adapter: postgresql
>   database: hello
>   username: postgres
>   password: zues
>   pool: 5
>   timeout: 5000

and code like this:

```
IO.foreach("db.txt") do |line|
  i = 0
    while line[i] != '\n'
      print line[i]
      i = i+1
    end
    puts
end
```

but it only prints the first line like this:

> adapter: postgresql

Comment: There's one end too much in your code.

Comment: @Borsunho thanks for the mistake but the error is not fixed

Comment: Check my answer posted below, bro.

Comment: did it work for you, @ChandraShekhar?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing simplier. All you have to do is write `"\n"` instead of `'\n'`, sir:

```
IO.foreach("db.txt") do |line|
  i = 0
    while line[i] != "\n"
      print line[i]
      i = i+1
    end
    puts
end
```

However *hspandher* is right in his post - the way you are trying to do this, is not Ruby way.
Possibly either you are new to ruby and you were coding in C/C++/Java previously or you just have to implement this way (homework, w/e), but whatever you gonna do with this piece of code later, iterating char by char is not the most successful option.

Anyway your problem has been solved with my code above, feel free to test it.

Answer (score 0):

This code prints character by character on the screen except for \n

```
IO.foreach("db.txt") do |line|
    i = 0
        while line[i] != "\n"
            puts line[i]
            i = i+1
        end
end
```